# How can I popup an alert of "Hello" after clicking collapsible under JqueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I am using JqueryMobile 1.3.2. I would like to add some event when user clicking the header. For example, popup an alert "Hello". What can I do?

```
<div data-role="collapsible">

  <h3>I'm a header</h3>

  <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Enable yourself look at the demos: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/ and read quick notes, I am very sure you will nail this bro `:)` usually show some code along with your html i.e. what have you tried so far. **Collapsible demo** : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/collapsibles/

Comment: Yes I've read the official guideline. However, it's different from button or input which something we can trigger, I cannot find a proper way to add event inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to two events instead of binding a `click` event. *Collapsibles* have two special events you can listen to and run code when they trigger, `expand` and `collapse`.

For **jQuery Mobile 1.4** `collapsibleexpand` and `collapsiblecollapse`.

```
$(".selector").on("collapse", function () {
  alert("Collapsed");
});

$(".selector").on("expand", function () {
  alert("Expanded");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wB2C5/)**

Comment: Thanks! Although both answers are working, your example is better because it's more align to JQM coding behavior and can control both collapse and expand!

Comment: @user2699714 You're welcome :) True, using jQM events is more reliable and isn't complicated. You can manipulate DOM faster using those events.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Selector').bind('expand', function () {
   alert('Expand')
}).bind('collapse', function () {
    alert('collapse')
});


<div data-role="collapsible" id="Selector">
   <h4>Heading</h4>
   <p>How can I popup an alert of “Hello” after clicking collapsible under JqueryMobile</p>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rmsH3/)